# auto.arima (Hyndman R package)

Tags: forecasting, arima, autoregressive, moving-average

I am running an auto arima on a datase that yields two tries as revealed by using trace=TRUE as:

```
  arima <- auto.arima(
    series,
    max.p = 2,
    max.q = 1,
    max.d = 1,
    seasonal = FALSE, ic = "aicc", stepwise = FALSE,
    lambda = 0.6153823,
    allowdrift = TRUE, 

    trace=TRUE
  )
```

I get;

```
 ARIMA(0,1,0)                    : -215.3494
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : -215.8672
 ARIMA(0,1,1)                    : -213.7759
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : -216.0212
 ARIMA(1,1,0)                    : -213.9535
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : -215.9919
 ARIMA(1,1,1)                    : -211.7276
 ARIMA(1,1,1) with drift         : -213.5953
 ARIMA(2,1,0)                    : -211.9597
 ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift         : -213.4425
 ARIMA(2,1,1)                    : -209.0447
 ARIMA(2,1,1) with drift         : -211.2317



 Best model: ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         


 ARIMA(0,1,0)                    : -126.0201
 ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift         : -126.8844
 ARIMA(0,1,1)                    : -124.1706
 ARIMA(0,1,1) with drift         : -126.4151
 ARIMA(1,1,0)                    : -124.2922
 ARIMA(1,1,0) with drift         : -126.5096
 ARIMA(1,1,1)                    : -122.0674
 ARIMA(1,1,1) with drift         : -123.951
 ARIMA(2,1,0)                    : -122.4731
 ARIMA(2,1,0) with drift         : -123.951
 ARIMA(2,1,1)                    : Inf
 ARIMA(2,1,1) with drift         : Inf



 Best model: ARIMA(0,1,0) with drift
```

The final chosen ARIMA is the one from the second batch, i.e. has a higher acai selection criterion (-126.8844) than the entire first batch. It seems the difference comes from maxium differencing (i.e. allowing for d>0).

On the surface, my understanding was that the auto.arima function chooses the model with the lowest acai criterion cf. https://otexts.com/fpp2/arima-r.html, see step d). Is it possible that there are other selection processes at play, which are not clear to me here?

Dataset here:

```
series <- structure(c(0.139234883720175, 0.147044036113071, 0.143178940762853, 
0.148766015439559, 0.136362519710497, 0.134462433385976, 0.134348348389337, 
0.137193197579132, 0.137272495688048, 0.140420943613473, 0.134804039348136, 
0.136532410307284, 0.143009263115035, 0.134704494931747, 0.132537887370838, 
0.132748829915555, 0.133106532745161, 0.134003025316618, 0.131440584469317, 
0.13333390514476, 0.129715319968629, 0.127374808548618, 0.121833843769989, 
0.114360563689702, 0.114014473970318, 0.114461360049305, 0.122030283003886, 
0.116362450423606, 0.113153368832032, 0.119310361323494, 0.110418991418141, 
0.108975830107555, 0.104369639062171, 0.0988382214440201, 0.0982304613082107, 
0.0936612969584415), dim = c(36L, 1L), dimnames = list(NULL, 
    "value"), tsp = c(1984, 2019, 1), class = "ts")
```

Comment: Can you edit your post to make your code reproducible? Please use `dput` to include your `series`, and cut everything down to a minimal example that exhibits your issue. Also, which version of `forecast` and `R` are you using? Mine (`forecast_8.21.1`) does not know a `no.oscillation` parameter.

Comment: Thanks. Coming up. 

```no.oscillation``` is custom made. Will remove (not needed for this).
forecast package is ```forecast_8.17.0```

Comment: Thank you. `allowdrift` seems to be `TRUE`. What value does `lambda` have? Using `lambda=0.2` does not give me (in my newer `forecast` version) two outputs. Can you update to the newest version?

Comment: Incidentally, `arima()` is a base R command... using this as a variable name can lead to unpleasant surprises.

Comment: Hm. Running your exact code including your lambda value does not give me two outputs. Have you tried running this through a completely new R console? I wonder whether your custom wrapping for `no.oscillation` might have introduced some unwanted effects.

Comment: You are right. It actually comes from the following, which is unfortunate in this case:

```auto.arima.3 <- function(..., lambda=1) {
  arima <- auto.arima.2(..., lambda=lambda)
  if (
    lambda < 0.9
    &&
    "drift" %in% names(arima$coef)
    &&
    arima$coef[["drift"]] < 0
  ){
    arima <- auto.arima.2(..., lambda=0.0001)
  }
  return(arima)
}

auto.arima <- auto.arima.3```

Thanks alot. Good spotted.